# C++/Java serialization library suitable for socket stream?

Tags: java, c++, serialization, networking, tcp

I need to write a server in C++/Obj-C that can receive streamed data from several clients built in Java and C++.  The challenge: I need to serialize and deserialize the data structures efficiently.  One C++ client will be generating 128x96x2-dimensional float arrays, plus some metadata, about 30 times per second (video features).  A Java client will be generating a smaller feature vector -- probably 200 values, 1-10 times per second. I've about resigned myself to rolling my own implementation, but before I do, I'd like to ask recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) supports your required languages and streaming of serialized data structures, but I am not sure how you would best handle those large arrays.  There is some ongoing work [here](https://github.com/jhartman/Google-Protocol-Buffers/tree/java-optimizations) in this area of protobuf for Java - background [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/protobuf@googlegroups.com/msg04866.html).

With this in mind, you might be able to produce something that works using Java and C++ protobuf, with custom code in C++ to handle the Java array encoding in that branch.

Comment: This looks great, thank you for the reference! The tutorials/documentation only seem to show how to encode single values, though, not arrays. The `repeated` keyword seems in-the-ballpark, but it seems sloppy to rely on shoving each element of a large array into a repeated variable.

Comment: @Alterscape - yes, that's a recognized deficiency of the library now, sounds like they are working on a Java solution but I did not look at the code for that - if that is an improvement, you could add your own code for that encoding on the C++ side, I imagine (it's open source).