# Android/C++ data serialization

Tags: android, c++, serialization

What is the best way or library to exchange data/serialize structures between c++ server and android client? Performance is essential. Compression is preffered.
Right now I am trying to implement packet exchange using [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) 
(https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java) - for android side.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4178075/942596) seems related.

Answer (score 1):

Msgpack/protobuf are fine for this task.

But Msgpack does not fully supports 'optional' values or versioning (it can be important for your application).
On the other hand, I'm not sure that all protobuf-RPC implementations are compatible to each other (Msgpack-RPC protocol is the same for every platform/implementation).

Comment: Thank's you have reassured me)