# Is there versioning capability in Msgpack

Tags: c++, serialization, msgpack

I'm evaluating Msgpack(C++) as a serialization library in my current project. It seems to satisfy most of my needs except one and I didn't find much information online about it. Does Msgpack support reading different versions of data structures which I will be serializing?

for example, I serialize following structure:

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  float b;
};
```

And later above structure evolved into:

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  float b;
  std::string c;
};
```

Is it possible to read previously serialized structure into newer one using Msgpack? Boost library handles it by adding `VERSION` metadata along with the structure.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579730/android-c-data-serialization You could think of other alternatives like google protocol buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that. If you pack `foo_v1` and then unpack it, then convert it as `foo_v2`, `a` and `b` are filled with packed values.

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct foo_v1 {
    int a;
    float b;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(a, b); // pack as ARRAY, order is important
};

struct foo_v2 {
    int a;
    float b;
    std::string c;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(a, b, c); // pack as ARRAY, order is important
};

int main() {
    foo_v1 v1 { 123, 45.67 };
    std::stringstream ss;
    msgpack::pack(ss, v1);

    auto oh = msgpack::unpack(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size());
    auto v2 = oh.get().as<foo_v2>();
    std::cout << "a: " << v2.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << v2.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c: " << v2.c << std::endl;
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/91wRtVdJJCC5IEDx

Similarly, if you pack `foo_v2` and then unpack it, then convert it as `foo_v1`, `a` and `b` are filled with packed values, `c` is sliced (ignored).

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct foo_v1 {
    int a;
    float b;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(a, b); // pack as ARRAY, order is important
};

struct foo_v2 {
    int a;
    float b;
    std::string c;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(a, b, c); // pack as ARRAY, order is important
};

int main() {
    foo_v2 v2 { 123, 45.67, "hello" };
    std::stringstream ss;
    msgpack::pack(ss, v2);

    auto oh = msgpack::unpack(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size());
    auto v1 = oh.get().as<foo_v1>();
    std::cout << "a: " << v1.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << v1.b << std::endl;
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/mxmSkVHebZFiOM1q

These examples are using `MSGPACK_DEFINE` macro. See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_adaptor#defining-custom-adaptors.
It is for packing/converting as ARRAY by default. So the order is important. 
If you use `MSGPACK_DEFINE_MAP`, the user classes are packing/converting as MAP. The key of `MAP` is the variable name by default. You can change it using `MSGPACK_NVP` see https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_adaptor#since-210. The value of `MAP` is the value of the member variable.
`MAP` is more flexible than `ARRAY` but inefficient.

If you use `MSGPACK_DEFINE_MAP`, you don't need to care about order.

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct foo_v1 {
    int a;
    float b;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE_MAP(a, b); // pack as MAP
};

struct foo_v2 {
    int a;
    std::string c;
    float b;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE_MAP(a, c, b); // pack as MAP, c is at the middle position
};

int main() {
    foo_v2 v2 { 123, "hello", 45.67,  };
    std::stringstream ss;
    msgpack::pack(ss, v2);

    auto oh = msgpack::unpack(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size());
    auto v1 = oh.get().as<foo_v1>();
    std::cout << "a: " << v1.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << v1.b << std::endl;
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ozihpwXMJRpOhzT4

Here is more complecated example:
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/master/example/cpp03/map_based_versionup.cpp

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/IUp94Tc4MiT4kU07

Comment: Thank you so much for the example! This answers my question.